# UIScrollView issue

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollView with textviews as subviews. Now in my app there are multiple UIScrollViews like these. And depending on the selection I display the appropriate UIScrollView on top of the previous view. This works fine in all cases except when the previous view has been a UIScrollView as well. In this case the behavior I get is of two UIScrollViews stacked on top of each other and both the views capture the scrolling events. The textViews from previous scrollView is also visible (not editable though) and overlaps and causes all sorts of issues. The thing is a full screen UIScrollView placed as subview to a previous view causes problems when the previous view is a full screen UIScrollView as well.

Any pointers on how to overcome this would be great. Is there anyway to notify the parent scrollview of the child's scroll events and move it the exact same way so this mess is masked?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a crude solution by presenting an empty view before I present the next scrollView. Added the scrollView as subview to this empty view (with a BG image) and added the to-be presented scrollView as a subview to it and then presenting this on top of the previous scrollView.

Answer (score 1):

[UIScrollView documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html) says:

> **Important**: You should not embed UIWebView or UITableView objects in UIScrollView objects. If you do so, unexpected behavior can result because touch events for the two objects can be mixed up and wrongly handled.

As far as I know, it is generally not recommended to embed a UIScrollView subclass instance in a UIScrollView. In one of my projects, which is an IM application, I have a UIScrollView that contains many UITableViews, it works when you try enough but it really takes a lot of effort to handle subtle bugs and make it work properly.

It is really hard to say something useful for your problem without diving in to code, but i can recommend you to not add UIScrollViews one on to another like a stack. I'd try doing it by allowing only one UIScrollView at top, and removing others. When you need to show another one, remove the top one from view hierarchy and add the new one. I wish this helps, good luck.